# Call to a member function setActive() on boolean

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I encountered the following issue when i was trying to install a module. When I try to access the admin panel on my magento I get:

> Call to a member function setActive() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\magento\module-backend\Model\View\Result\Page.php on line 27

I disabled all third party and custom modules, I compiled the code but I still get this error.

EDIT: I did a `var_dump($itemId)` just below the line where the error is and the `$itemid` is '`Magento_Backend::dashboard`'.

EDIT 2: The error is because the line "`$this->layout->getBlock('menu');`" above returns false. I can't find though why this is happening

Comment: No solution yet. Keep looking at https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13504
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11526

Answer (score 25):

I will try this to solve problem
if `setActive()` `error()` arrived after `setup:di:compile` then becauese of session is destroy.

So go to Magento directory and then delete file generated by di:compile is path :-

`magento\generated\metadata\global.php` delete this file then after refersh your page.

> This is temporary solution for this error in local server.

Comment: I already removed it and still not working.

Comment: It actually worked for me, however, is it safe to remove this file?

Comment: yes it's safe to remove as long as you do a setup:upgrade afterwards

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me as well.

Comment: Worked !!!  thanx you saved my time :)

Answer (score 8):

I had the same situation in the development of own modules (I created/changed layout files for grid in adminhtml). Try to clean cache **and** switch to development mode:

```
$ ./bin/magento cache:clean
$ ./bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

I suppose some cached stuff is not cleaned on `cache:clean` & `setup:di:compile` in production mode. You can switch back to production mode back if error will gone in development mode.

Comment: I think I did the same thing! It was a layout file issue. Thanks!

Comment: php bin/magento setup:di:compile - executed this command and resolved my issue

Answer (score 2):

Do try to remove **`pub/static`** and **`var/cache`** then run the below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

After that it will work

Comment: @Priyank I was in the same situation, I google it and find that question on google, once I got to resolve the issue, I taught its better to share the solution. Maybe you just dislike because you need some badge or something else.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the layout xml of this controller path is not loading properly.

Check that the name and the namespace of the controller is matching with the layout file name. Take care of the case sensitivity.

For example:

- `custom_module_admin_customcontroller_action.xml`
- `namespace Custom\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Customcontroller` and not `CustomController`

Answer (score 0):

When you do `getBlock()` it returns the block or it returns false if it can not find it.
You need to have a check in place something like :

```
$block = $layout->getBlock('name);
If ($block){
//execute the rest
}
```

The reason why it can not find your block is something i would need more details for. If you are using a layout xml file be sure that the block and the class of the block does not have any errors.

Answer (score 0):

**Temporary Fix :**
Remove "generated\metadata\global.php" and it will fix.

**Permanent Fix :**
The problem is that the layout xml of this controller path is not loading properly.

Check that the name and the namespace of the controller is matching with the layout file name. Take care of the case sensitivity.

For example:

custom_module_admin_customcontroller_action.xml
Check the namespace of the Controller Properly

`Custom\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Customcontroller`

and not

`Custom\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\CustomController`