# Magento2.3.0 In production mode when i go to admin category click getting error

Tags: magento2, admin

I am using Magento2.3.0 and our website is production mode when i go to admin side in category getting error. i apply all command but it may be issue in generated folder inside because using compile command after getting issue my error comes below

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setActive() on boolean in /home/XXXXX/public_html/XVXVXVXV.co.uk/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php:27 Stack trace: #0 /home/XXXXX/public_html/XVXVXVXV.co.uk/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Edit.php(105): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page->setActiveMenu('Magento_Catalog...') #1 /home/XXXXX/public_html/XVXVXVXV.co.uk/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Edit/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit->execute() #2 /home/XXXXX/public_html/XVXVXVXV.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(108): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor->execute() #3 /home/XXXXX/public_html/XVXVXVXV.co.uk/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(231): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #4 /home/XXXXX/public_html/econaturalproduct in /home/XXXXX/public_html/XVXVXVXV.co.uk/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php on line 27
```

In one category below product not getting on frontend side.

Comment: check with this url - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/204954/call-to-a-member-function-setactive-on-boolean  i hope its working to you.

Comment: already applied it but not getting solution

Comment: pleae look at my other issue "https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/282236/magento2-purchased-theme-inside-testimonial-module-using-when-add-testimonial?noredirect=1#comment404099_282236"

Comment: i m stucking  this issue on live only

Answer (score 0):

Enable Maintenance Mode

```
bin/magento maintenance:enable
```

[Clear Generated Code:](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/php/php_clear-dirs.html)

```
rm -rf /path-to-magento/generated/code/* /path-to-magento/generated/metadata/*
```

Upgrade Magento:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Compile Dependency injection:

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Re-index:

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Clean the cache:

```
bin/magento cache:clean
```

Disable Maintenance:

```
bin/magento maintenance:disable
```